# create a solution file (.sln) in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I created my own project using VS Professional 2012, but I couldn't find my Project.sln Solution File!? Is there any solution that I can get it within my solution explorer?
Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Why would you need it in your solution explorer?

Comment: Yes, Please :( .....

Comment: Install the Everything search application from http://www.voidtools.com/ and look for *.sln

Comment: Sorry Which File do I need to download?

Comment: The .sln file doesn't show up in the solution explorer, except as the top level solution. It would however show up in your file system. If you use Windows Explorer to navigate to your file system and find the correct folder, do you see the .sln file?

Comment: I can't find it!! I have done a project on VS 2010 and got the sln file in the solution, but why is it missing in vs 2012. Is there any way I can get it?

Comment: Describe what you mean by "got the solution". It might be helpful if you upload a screenshot. If you right click the solution in Visual Studio and go to "Open Folder in File Explorer", then go up one directory, do you see the .sln file there?

Comment: Yes,I can see it now. I created my project using my USB stick. It was hard for me to re-open my project!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to see the actual solution file in Solution Explorer. Click on your solution name (ie. `Solution: 'ConsoleApplication1' (1 project)`) in the Solution Explorer and your Properties tab should give you the path of the *.sln file.

[image]